# Is it possible to connect thermal receipt printer to Google Open print?

Tags: printing, receipt, google-cloud-print

I am looking at connecting a thermal receipt printer to Google Open Print, is this possible? and if so are you aware of any thermal printers that I can purchase?

The reason for the above is that I have a takeaway shop with an online store. When an order is placed the order then gets printed on an A4 Injet printer. This is wasting me lots of paper and ink, Ideally I'd like it do be done with a thermal printer. I know the website can work with this I just need to make sure I can get a thermal printer to work with Google Open print.

Comment: What is Google Open Print? You don't mean Cloud Print?

Comment: We use thermal printers but it's for ie only. Active x

Comment: why exactly are you using google open print?

Comment: Did you find a Google Cloud Print receipt printer anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the Espon TM88V Receipt printer. Once it was installed on a computer and working any printer can be added to Google Print. Please know that the printer I choose was a nightmare to get a driver for an up to date OS such as Windows 7 & 8. This printer was only supported for XP from my research but after trying all drivers for old OS's it worked. There are now drivers being made by others to support newer OS's.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot thermal receipt printers available in the market. EPSON is provides standard reciept pritners which are very good. 
You can opt for TMT88 series which are pretty good.

But not sure about the google open print.